# Middleware on a specific route

Tags: http, go, middleware, go-chi

As in `go-chi`, set middleware at the level of individual routes, and not just globally for all routes

```
// Routes creates a REST router
func Routes() chi.Router {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(middleware.Captcha)

    r.Post("/", Login)

    return r
}
```

How for `Login` to specify a unique middleware or to exclude from the general middleware?

Comment: You can chain middlewares as usuall. Their docmention that it fully implements `Router` interface

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options.  The natural way, supported by any router:

```
r.Post("/", middlewareFunc(Login))
```

Or if you want to use a Chi-specific way, create a new Group for the one specific endpoint:

```
loginGroup := r.Group(nil)
loginGroup.Use(middleware)
loginGroup.Post("/", Login)
```